# Configuring tmux to use Windows key for prefix

Tags: linux, tmux

Is it possible to use the Windows key in tmux?

I'd like to bind my commands to use it as the prefix.

Comment: Does your windows key cause your terminal emulator to send any (special) data to its tty? A common diagnostic technique is to type stuff at `cat -v`. When you do this, does anything show up when you type your Windows key by itself (or, when pressing it with another key, anything besides the normal output for that other key)? Unless your terminal emulator sends (special) output for the key, then there is no way *tmux* can know that you have pressed it.

Comment: Was looking the same question and found more explanation there:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1636/how-do-i-bind-the-tmux-prefix-to-a-super

bu I guess you might have discovered it since then.